# How to build side navigation using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a side navigation menu using jquery.I want two navigations - left and right and also want that when I click outside of navigation, it should be closed. Below is my code.

CSS for styling

```
.panel > h1 {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 30%;
    padding: 1em 0;
    color: #efebe9;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.panel > a {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0.75em;
    padding: 0.375em;
    max-width: 22%;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #efebe9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.panel > a.close {
    right: 0.5em;
}

.panel {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: #5e412f;
    border: 1px solid black;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.panel-left {
    left: -80%;
    z-index: 1001;
}

.panel-right {
    right: -80%;
    z-index: 1001;
}

.panel > ul.list {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.list {
    position: relative;
    margin: 1em 2.5%;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: white;
    width: 95%;
}

.list > li > a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em 0.5em;
    color: #05a800;
    font-size: 1em text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.list > li {
    border-left: 1px solid #a1887f;
    border-right: 1px solid #a1887f;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a1887f;
}

.list > li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid #a1887f;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.list > li:last-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

HTML Markup

```
<div id="panel-left" class="panel panel-left">
    <h1>Left panel </h1>
    <a href="#" class="close" id="close-left">Close</a>
    <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-right">
    <h1>Left panel </h1>
    <a href="#" class="close" id="close-right">Close</a>
    <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var left_btn, right_btn, left_panel, right_panel, close_left_nav, close_right_nav;
    left_btn = $("#btn-left");
    right_btn = $("#btn-left");
    left_panel = $(".panel-left")[0];
    right_panel = $(".panel-right")[0];
    close_left_nav = $("#close-left");
    close_right_nav = $("#close-right");
    left_btn.click(function() {
        left_panel.css("left", 0);
        close_left_nav.click(function() {
            left_panel.css("left", "-80%");
        });
    });
    right_btn.click(function() {
        right_panel.css("right", 0);
        close_right_nav.click(function() {
            right_panel.css("right", "-80%");
        });
    });
});
```

But its not working. It works when I use $(".panel-left"); or $(".panel-right");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**Html**

```
<button id="btn-left">Left</button>
<button id="btn-right">Right</button>
<div id="panel-left" class="panel panel-left">
    <h1>Left panel </h1>
    <a href="#" class="close" id="close-left">Close</a>
    <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-right">
    <h1>Left panel </h1>
    <a href="#" class="close" id="close-right">Close</a>
    <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link Item1</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Java Script**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


     $(document).ready(function() {
    var left_btn, right_btn, left_panel, right_panel, close_left_nav, close_right_nav;
    left_btn = $("#btn-left");
    right_btn = $("#btn-right");
    left_panel = $(".panel-left");
    right_panel = $(".panel-right");
    close_left_nav = $("#close-left");
    close_right_nav = $("#close-right");
    open_div=false;
    left_btn.click(function() {
      if(open_div == false){
        left_panel.css("left", 0);        
         open_div=true;
        close_left_nav.click(function() {
            left_panel.css("left", "-80%");
            right_btn.attr("disabled",false);
            open_div=false;
        });
      }
    });
    right_btn.click(function() {
      if(open_div == false){        
        right_panel.css("right", 0);

        open_div=true;
        close_right_nav.click(function() {
            right_panel.css("right", "-80%");
            left_btn.attr("disabled",false);
            open_div=false;
        });
      }
    });

    $(document).on("mouseup","body",function(e) {    
    container=$('.panel-left');    
    if (!container.is(e.target) && (!right_btn.is(e.target)) && (!left_btn.is(e.target)) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.css("left", "-80%");
        right_btn.attr("disabled",false);
        open_div=false;
    }

    container=$('.panel-right');

    if (!container.is(e.target) && (!left_btn.is(e.target)) && (!right_btn.is(e.target)) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) 
    {
        container.css("right", "-80%");
        left_btn.attr("disabled",false);
        open_div=false;
    }

  });
});

    </script>
```

Comment: It works for me. When I click outside of navigation, it hides, but when left navigation is open and I click on right button, left navigation hides and right navigation gets open which I don't want

Comment: I think what I want can easily be done if we disable the all links that are not in side navigations. So when links are disabled, they will behave like other html tags and only one navigation will close and other will not open at the same time

Comment: I think what I want can easily be done if we disable the all links that are not in side navigation. So when left side navigation is open, all other links  are disabled, they will behave like other html tags and on clicking outside the navigation , only left navigation will close and other will not open at the same time

Comment: Yes if you want only one menu open at at time then  you can disable other.

Comment: Sorry to say but your previous code was much better than this. Because it opens both navigationa at same time, while previous code opens only one navigation at same time. The only drawback in previous code was that if your left navigation is open and you click on right navigation btn then left nav will hide and right nave will show.

Comment: What I want is that if left nav is open and you click on right nav btn or outside of left nav, only left nave should close. Right nab will not open

Comment: ok so may be You are using link `(<a>)` .So you try my edited answer. let ,e know its working or not

Comment: Its not working. If left nav is open and I click on right nav btn, left nave is hiding and right nave is opening

Comment: I have achieved success in making what I want. I modified the code and its working. Thanks bro for helping me.